# React Native - Invariant Violation - i18next integration

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-i18next

I am trying to create a `react-native` application, I'm currently at the starting point and I cannot understand an issue that I encountered.

I need to integrate `i18next` for translations. I did this by following their [step-by-step tutorial](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks)

I have the following code

> App.js

```js
import React, { Suspense, Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Colors, } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <Text>{t('index.welcome')}</Text>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={styles.scrollView}>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <MyComponent />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
});

export default App;
```

The issue here is that I get an `Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component` error

If I change `MyComponent` to the following the application works

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  return <Text>Anything</Text>;
};
```

So the issue here for me seems to be the `useTranslation()` hook.

What am I missing here?

> LE

I was missing the `namespace` in the `useTranslation()`

I've added it `useTranslations('translation')` but still I have the same issue

The issue seems to be with the path for the translation files which cannot be parsed

`i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing /translations/en/translation.json to json`

In React the files would be public available via the `public` folder, in React-Native how should this be used? I think that the app cannot access that folder, where should the folder be placed?

> LE2

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },

    backend: {
      loadPath: '/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

And the `translations` folder is placed in the root of the project

Comment: where is your i18n setting file?

Comment: @hongdevelop I've added the config in the post